# How are delete and delete[] implemented?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

When I use `new []` to apply memory. In the end, I use `delete` to free memory (not `delete[]`). Will this cause memory leak?

Two types:

1. Builtin types, like `int`, `char`, `double` ...
   I am not sure.
2. class types.

I think may free leak. because the destruct function.

Many people and some books tell me, `new[]` -> `delete[]` ; `new` -> `delete`. 

I want to know why.
so I check vs2010 source code, it must be use memory pool mechanism. It is long and complex . I can't continue read.

How are `delete` and `delete[]` implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I use new [] to apply memory. In end , I use delete to free memeory(not delete[]).Must be memory leak ?

If you use `new[]`, and then `delete` (not `delete[]`), then according to the langauge specification, it invokes undefined-behavior which means anything could happen. It *may* cause memory leak or may not. No such guarantee is given by the language, nor by the compiler.

> Many people and some books tell me, new[]->delete[]; new->delete . I want to know why ?

Short answer : because the specification says so.

Long answer: the functions which implement`new` and `new[]` are implemented differently: `new` assumes memory of one item is to be allocated, while `new[]` assumes memory of `n` item is to be allocated where `n` is passed to the function as argument. So to undo the process (i.e to deallocate the memory), there should be two functions as well : `delete` and `delete[]` which are implemented differently, each makes some assumption about the memory allocated by their counterparts. For example, `delete` simply assumes memory allocated for one item is to be deallocated; on the other hand `delete[]` needs to know the number of items for which memory is to be deallocated, so it assumes that `new[]` stores the *number* of items somewhere in the allocated memory, most commonly in the begginning of the allocated memory, and so `delete[]` first reads that portion of memory which stores the number of items, and then deallocates the memory, accordingly.

Note that `new` and `new[]` each calls the default constructor to construct the object(s) in the allocated memory, and `delete` and `delete[]` calls the destructor to destruct the object before deallocating the memory.

Comment: though true, it is not the question [I *think*] - he asks about how is it implemented [I agree the question was not very clear before I editted it...]

Comment: First, thank you. amit, is right. I want to know "how is it implemented? "

Comment: @chinazhangjie: I think I've explained *in brief* how each is implemented. You want an *actual* implementation?

Comment: @chinazhangjie: Nawaz's edit ["Long Answer"] give a short description how it is implemented. I believe the editted answer explains the issue at hand pretty well.

Comment: @Nawaz: Before today, I alway think the C++ language specification. But today, I see a funciton in my company[I am a intern] source code. He use new[] ,but use delete to free. So I ask a colleague, He said , the builtin type may not cause a memery leak. I' am in doubt about it. So I try ,and find the answer.

Comment: @chinazhangjie: Tell him that it is undefined-behavior, which may cause memory leak. There are infinite number of possibilities when your program has undefined-behavior. It may crash immediately, or it may not. and so on.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a memory leak; it's *undefined behavior*. That's much worse.

Calling `delete` on memory allocated by `new[]` can lead to corrupting the heap, which can crash your application. Not immediately, of course, because that would be too useful. It will crash sometime later, long after the heap was corrupted to make it almost impossible to track down.

Always use `delete[]` with `new[]`. Actually, *never use `new[]`* to begin with. Use a `std::vector` unless you have very special and specific needs.

> I want to know why ?

Why does it matter? It's *wrong* and leads to a broken program. It's wrong because the C++ standard says so.

However, if you insist on a reason...

Notice that you can allocate any number of items with `new[]`. You can put any counting number (aka: positive integer) there. So you can have `new int[50]` or `new int[someIntegerVariable]`. It's all good.

Also notice that `delete[]` does *not* take a count. Well... how is that possible? If you allocate 50 `int`s, obviously `delete` needs to know how many you allocated, right? But you don't have to tell it; it automagically knows.

How? Because `new int[50]` allocates *more* than just an array of 50 `int`s. It also allocates enough space to hold the size of the allocation. Think of it as allocating 51 `int`s but only letting you use 50 of them.

Then, `delete[]` comes along. It figures out where to find the count that `new[]` allocated. And it uses that count to deallocate the memory.

`delete` does *not* do this. Therefore, it *cannot* deallocate the memory correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Nawaz is correct that it is 'because the specification says so'.

The implementation reason behind it is that when you call `delete`, the compiler adds a call to the destructor of the object before releasing the memory.

In the case of an array, the number of calls to destructors depends on the number of objects allocated which is only known at runtime. So `new[]` saves extra information regarding number of objects which `delete[]` uses.

This information is not needed when using `new`/`delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do so. Though, for most implementations, you can safely delete a array with delete instead of delete[], **as long as the element type of the array don't have destructor**.

For a type with destructor, new [] will have to record the length of the array somewhere in the dynamic allocated memory block. delete[] will destruct every element base on that, and finally free the memory block. And delete will not recognize such a structure. Maybe it's memory leak, maybe you will get some exception.